# Using split function in Pandas bracket indexer

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm trying to keep the text rows in a data frame that contains a specific **word**. I have tried the following:

```
df['hello' in df['text_column'].split()]
```

and received the following error:

> 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Please pay attention that I'm trying to check if they contain a word, not a char series, so `df[df['text_column'].str.contains('hello')]` is not a solution because in that case, 'helloss' or 'sshello' would also be returned as True.

Comment: what is i/p and desired o/p, unable to understand `I'm trying to check if they contain a word, not a char series,`

Comment: I think they want only "xxx hello xxx" and not "xxxhelloxxx"

Comment: Use regex meta-character `\b` (word boundary) encompassing the word ?  E.g. `df[df['text_column'].str.contains(r'\bhello\b')]`

Comment: Good idea Seabean but I guess that would be computationally expensive. I'm repeating this on 8m rows for 10000 words!

Comment: what is the issue with `df[df['text_column'].str.contains('hello')]`?

Comment: Using `\b` is not as expensive as other regex operation requiring backtracking or lookaheads.   Just take a try.

Comment: I tried .srt.split() as well and didn't work. No, split() is faster. Check the answer provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer in addition to the regex answer mentioned above would be to use split combined with the map function like below

```
df['keep_row'] = df['text_column'].map(lambda x: 'hello' in x.split())
df = df[df['keep_row']]
```

OR

```
df = df[df['text_column'].map(lambda x: 'hello' in x.split())]
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for and as I expected, it's 1.6 times faster than the regex solution.